# DSL for triggering cron with a parameter. I have defined the parameter in the job above but unable to pass it in the cron using dsl scripts

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I have created the parameter but i am unable to pass that variable while creating the `cron` job.

```
job("dev_testing") 
{
  parameters
  {
    booleanParam('security_scan', true)
    choiceParam('OPTION', ['false (default)', 'true',])
  }
  triggers
  {
    cron('H 23 * * 6 %security_scan; true')
  }
}
```

Following is the error:
ERROR: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object (javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext parameterizedTimerTrigger script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know which plugins you have installed, but the [Parameterized Scheduler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin) should help you with your use case.

Per their [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md), the below should work:

```
triggers {
   parameterizedCron('''H 23 * * 6 %security_scan=true''')
}
```

This also worked for me:

```
triggers {
    parameterizedTimerTrigger {
        parameterizedSpecification('H 23 * * 6 %security_scan=true')
    }
}
```

Comment: The one at the bottom worked for me, the one on top not.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread - but I just ran into this lately and couldn't get **multiple triggers** to work for the life of me. Finally I got it working so:

```
triggers {
        parameterizedTimerTrigger {
            parameterizedSpecification('''H 21 * * 0-4 %APPLICATION=php
H 23 * * 0-4 %APPLICATION=java''')

        }
}
```