# Jenkins DSL Syntax: Run Periodically With Parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to run a Jenkins DSL script to create jobs that build periodically with multiple parameters. So far, all I have found is parameterizedCron, but I believe that is for Jenkins Pipeline. Is there something similar for Jenkins DSL?

```
triggers {
    parameterizedCron('''
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Dev;TestCase=Student_Login
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Dev;TestCase=Student_Login
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Dev;TestCase=Student_Login
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Test;TestCase=Student_Login
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Test;TestCase=Student_Login
        H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Test;TestCase=Student_Login
        ''')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this answer.

This specifically works for the Jenkins Job DSL:

```
triggers {
    parameterizedTimerTrigger {
        parameterizedSpecification('''
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Dev;TestCase=${testCaseName}
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Dev;TestCase=${testCaseName}
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Dev;TestCase=${testCaseName}
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Test;TestCase=${testCaseName}
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Test;TestCase=${testCaseName}
            H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Test;TestCase=${testCaseName}
        ''')
    }
}
```

See [DSL for triggering cron with a parameter. I have defined the parameter in the job above but unable to pass it in the cron using dsl scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666920/dsl-for-triggering-cron-with-a-parameter-i-have-defined-the-parameter-in-the-jo)

Comment: Note: You still need to have the above wrapped in the `triggers {` block, but otherwise this worked

Comment: I like how you answered your own question.  Tip of the hat to you!